# Mysql LIKE script ignores trailing space pattern

Tags: mysql, sql-like, trailing-whitespace

I have a value `8122`  which has a trailing space at the end. Why does my sql script isn't catching this? This is the sql script:

```
select * from values where value like '% ' or value like ' %';
```

How to set the LIKE to be more sensitive in this sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of the tsrngsm before and after trimming

values is a reserved word in mysql

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `values `
WHERE LENGTH(value) > LENGTH(TRIM(value));
```

If you only want to oheck right spaces you use RTRIM and for left LTRIM

Incase you are looking for **only one space** you must check

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `values `
WHERE LENGTH(value)-1 = LENGTH(RTRIM(value))
    OR LENGTH(value)-1 = LENGTH(LTRIM(value));
```

Comment: I tried select * from test where LENGTH(value) < LENGTH(TRIM(value)); and it is not catching it actually.......so very weird....

Comment: you have to switch from > to < the triommed is smaller than  the original sorry

Comment: It should work but doesn't do it all the times https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=daa9bead30611f6bbbd495c2fe2aac11

Comment: God damn it, looks iek it depends on the mysql version. I cannot believe there is no way to detect this!!!!!! It is idiotic that they didn't put this distinction in......purely idiotic

Comment: i believe it is a bug so i reported it https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100008